# Finding out whether a DAG execution is a catchup or a regularly scheduled one

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow pipeline that starts with a FileSensor that may perform a number of retries (which makes sense because the producing process sometimes takes longer, and sometimes simply fails).

However when I restart the pipeline, as it runs in catchup mode, the retries in the file_sensor become spurious: if the file isn't there for a previous day, it wont materialize anymore.

Therefore my question: is it possible to make the behavior of a DAG-run contingent on whether that is currently running in a catch up or in a regularly scheduled run?

My apologies if this is a duplicated question: it seems a rather basic problem, but I couldn't find previous questions or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather simple.

- Set a `LatestOnlyOperator` upstream from the `FileSensor`
- Set an operator of any type you may need downstream from the `FileSensor` with its trigger rule set to `TriggerRule.ALL_DONE`.

Both `skipped` and `success` states count as "done" states, while an `error` state doesn't. Hence, in a "non-catch-up" run the `FileSensor` will need to succeed to give way to the downstream task, while in a catch-up run, the downstream task will start right away
after skipping the `FileSensor`.